# from gcn.utils import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gcn.utils'. Why can't it find it?

Tags: python, graph, neural-network

https://github.com/tkipf/gcn

I am trying to run this graph neural network code from github on my google colab. When I run the train.py file it gives me this error:
from gcn.utils import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gcn.utils'

I ran !python3 /content/drive/MyDrive/GNN/gcn/setup.py install - the setup file
and installed gcn as well - !pip install gcn
also made sure the directory was pointed to the right address.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The folder name is gcn，there are some conflicts,change the folder name, or remove all the `gcn.` from imports of `gcn.xx`.
such as: `from gcn.utils` -> `from utils`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).